# For each container not failing when it is returning 0 rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a for each container in my SSIS package.Inside that i have a script task in it.For each loop is iterating an object variable containing result from an Execute SQL task.
Everything is fine but the problem is for-each loop is not failing even when no rows are returned by previous sql task.
I want the package should fail when zero rows are returned.What should id do?

Answer (score 1):

I generally don't like to have packages fail just because the conditions for running aren't met. "Fail" can mean a phone call in the middle of the night. If this is something that needs to be addressed immediately, that's fine, but if it's not, I'd suggest a graceful exit instead.

A first thought would be to add another Execute SQL task in front of the one you have. In that task, execute the query you're using, but just return a row count, then pass that count to a variable. Then have two precedent constraints coming away from the new Execute SQL task.

Connect your first constraint to your existing Execute SQL task, but add a condition that your row count variable has to be >0.

Create another constraint with the condition that row count ==0. Connect that to, for instance, a Send Mail task that will generate an email saying there were no rows to process, and let the package execution end there.

Answer (score 0):

To have your package fail when there are no rows in the object variable, add an `OnPostExecute` Event Handler to the Execute SQL Task before the Foreach Loop.  In this Event Handler, create a Script Task that checks for existing rows in the object variable, then raises an error if none are found.  A `DataTable` object can be used as outlined below for this, and of course you can include whatever information in the error message that you need.  On the Script Task, the `FailPackageOnFailure` property will need to be set to true. 
 Although raising the error will already fail the package this prevents subsequent tasks from being executed.  The following outlines this further and a reference to the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace is necessary for this example.

```
        OleDbDataAdapter od = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        od.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::YourObjectVariable"].Value);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
           //If no processing is necessary, nothing needs to be done here.
                }
            else
               {
           Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Error", "No rows were available.", String.Empty, 0);
               }
```

Comment: Actually this job will be ran via TWS job scheduler.And your code giving me a message  box showing error and its going ahead only when i press OK on that message box.But i cant do it when i ran it via job.So what alternative line of code i can use?

Comment: Is there a MessageBox reference somewhere else in your Script Task?  The example I posted doesn't include any of these.  Try searching the code in the Script Task for MessageBox to see where this is coming from.

Comment: I ran the job through a job and its running without any stoppage but i am following error when it goes into that script task

Comment: Problem is resolved now.I forgot to put the object variable in script task